# how to check login username from more then one field in php like facebook

Tags: php, sql

This is my login form. I want to check username from company name or by nik_name, and password is mandatory field. As like facebook in which we can login from contact number or email, as like that i want to login from either company name or nick name.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control login-field" value=""
       placeholder="Username / Company Name" id="login-name"  name="email" />
<input type="password" class="form-control login-field" value=""
       placeholder="Password" id="login-pass" name="password" />
```

This is my SQL query to check nickname and password:

```
SELECT *
FROM buyers_login
WHERE nik_name = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail) . '"
  AND password = MD5("' . $loginPassword . '")
LIMIT 1
```

What will be the SQL query to check companyname or nickname with password ???

Comment: How could you choose a user from company name ?

Comment: actually i want ot make it as like facebook where the form accept mobile nu or email from a single text and password .. so i have two text box one is for companyname or nickname and other is for password ..

Comment: but multiple user may have same company name, so how is it possible to use it in this way?

Comment: customer code is used as a password ... to customer code will not been same... beside this i also check the company name at time of login so duplicacy will not be allowed for this, and nikname will be autogenerate from company name added by user and it check for duplicacy, if found any duplicacy in nikname then it will edit automatically with random number..

Comment: curious; is this a live site? I sure hope not @SiddharthVyas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your sql query to this

```
$loginEmail = trim($_POST['email']);  
$loginPassword  = trim($_POST['password']);  

SELECT * FROM buyers_login WHERE (nik_name = "'.
mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail).'" OR email = "'.
mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail).'") AND password = MD5("' .
$loginPassword . '") LIMIT 1
```

where `{text_email_or_company}` is taken from your post request, you can also change `name` fo you `email` input to username_or_company

**UPDATE**

if your provided query in question correct and working for you, then use this query but instead **company** use appropriate field from your `buyers_login` table

```
SELECT * FROM buyers_login WHERE (nik_name = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail) . '" OR company = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail) . '"  )  AND password = MD5("' . $loginPassword . '") LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Comparing `text_email_or_company` against both nik_name and company is not the right way to do this.

Comment: @bIgBoY and why you think so ? what is your argument ?

Comment: what if one user's company name is other user's nik_name ?

Comment: @bIgBoY that is too low probability as passwords can't be same in 99%, so for @SiddharthVyas asked case (user 2 inputs) i guess this solution is enough, othervice  he has to place 3-dth selecbox with options `Select Login Type` with options `Company` or `Username`

Comment: hello @armen query is not working ...  have a look this died query  SELECT * FROM buyers_login WHERE (nik_name = {"RESTORATION HARDWARE"} OR email = {"RESTORATION HARDWARE"}) nik_name = AND password = MD5("113") LIMIT 1

Comment: hi @SiddharthVyas you have to place instead {text_email_or_company} your inputs from php, ok let me update query for your exact cese

Comment: check added query after **update** in answer, take attention on `company` replacement note

Comment: this is the final query SELECT * FROM buyers_login WHERE (nik_name = {"RESTORATION HARDWARE"} OR email = {"RESTORATION HARDWARE"}) AND password = MD5("113") LIMIT 1

Comment: can you pls post your ` buyers_login` table structure in your question so i will be able to provide you exact query

Comment: Table structure for table `buyers_login`

--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buyers_login`
 (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  
`cut_code` text NOT NULL,
 
 `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 
 `nik_name` text NOT NULL,
 
 `contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
 
 `company` text NOT NULL,
  
`password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 
 `session_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 
 `date_registered` datetime NOT NULL,
  
`password_no_md5` text NOT NULL,
  
`status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=144 ;

Comment: hey @armen got the right sql query                  - > 'SELECT * FROM buyers_login WHERE (nik_name = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail).'" OR email = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail).'")   AND password = MD5("' . $loginPassword . '") LIMIT 1'............... we are mention it in ' { ' .. but without this bracket it working fine.... thanx for idea..

Comment: but in your question where asking to have compare it nigher with **company** or **username** ... ok anyway so if my answer was helpful for you then accept it

Comment: yeah your idea is as i want just i need to edit it by escape the  { } brackets ... working fine thanx..

Comment: Just a note that @bIgBoY is right, there is a chance of collision when someone has the same username as someone's company name, and they have the same password hash. Chances of that are slim, but don't rule them out. Someone could even deliberately create the second account to force the collision and prevent the first account from entering. If you're going to do this anyway, you'll have to manually check that username is not taken by other company name, and vice versa.